# Is there a way to get zsh to "forget" the casing of a filepath for tab completion?

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

zsh somehow "learned" imporper casing of a directory which contains code. Now whenever I tab complete, it always uses the invalid case.

I'm on OSX so the filesystem is case-insensitive. While it ends up in the right directory, vscode treats paths as case sensitive so things do not work properly.

For example, I have a directory named `"openapi"`. If I tab complete on `"open"` the terminal completes to `openAPI`.

Comment: Please give more details, examples, what means "improper", are use using some non-standard-stuff like oh-my-zsh?

Comment: Try the commands `rehash` or `hash -rf`.

Comment: @harrymc no go :(

Comment: @mpy updated with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the post
[Remove zsh autocomplete suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469320/remove-zsh-autocomplete-suggestion).

The accepted
[answer by thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469320/remove-zsh-autocomplete-suggestion)
explains the problem:

> This is probably the combination of the `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` and
> `CDABLE_VARS` options documented in `zshoptions(1)`.
>
> ```
> % PS1='%# ' zsh -f
> % setopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS
> % setopt CDABLE_VARS
> % autoload -U compinit
> % compinit
> % cd a        # was mashing tab here to no avail (nor asdf)
> cd: no such file or directory: a
> % hash -d asdf=/etc
> % cd asdf/    # "cd a" now tab completes
> ```
>
> (This was discovered by searching `zshoptions` for "dir" and "cd"
> related strings.)
>
> To turn this off disable one or more of those options (`unsetopt`) or
> remove the variable(s) that the completion code is finding.

A following
[answer by NOLFXceptMe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509561/17660)
adds :

> I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding
>
> `unsetopt CDABLE_VARS`
>
> line to my `.zshrc`

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer even though it didn't end up solving it for me (because it may have helped. I don't know).

It ended up being that I had a different directory "OpenAPI-Specification" in the same directory. renaming it to "openapi-spec" fixed the issue.